# Cannot Scaffold Login Page for .Net Core 3.1. Error: There was an error running the selected code generator package restore failed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, docker-compose, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

So, I've tried everything under the sun to Scaffold this Login page in my .Net Core 3.1 MVC application. I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity for authentication and I'm also debugging and developing using docker-compose. In docker I use a DB in AWS for development but locally I use a local SQL Server.  I keep getting this same error:

[image: Error Message]

Here's all the things I've tried:

1. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
2. Clearing the NuGet cache
3. Deleting and cloning the project from Git
4. Updating all of the NuGet packages
5. Deleting and reinstalling all of the NuGet packages
6. Downgrading all of the NuGet packages to 3.1.2
7. Downloading .Net 5.0 SDK and updating all of my packages to 5.0.3
8. Installing all of the respective Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration packages
9. Rebooted my machine
10. Reinstalled Visual Studio
11. Set the Start Up project as the MVC application instead of docker-compose
12. Several combinations of the above

Any ideas? From what I can tell at this point, it keeps erroring out when trying to install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package. Something tells me that there could be an issue caused by the different Sql Servers being used but I'm not sure how to figure that out because I'm able to build and run the project successfully both with the MVC application and the docker-compose as start up projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just downgraded every project and package back down to 3.1.0 across the board and that magically fixed everything. I'm not even sure why I was having an issue.

Comment: yea using 3.1.23 but downgraded to 3.1.0 and mines worked too